# Nunit SetupUpFixture syntax

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

What is the proper syntax to use when trying to implement the SetUpFixture ability in Nunit. This is what I have but I keep getting an error:

```
namespace Testing
{
    [SetUpFixture, RequiresSTA]
    public class SetupClass
    {
        public IE CASsite = new IE("awebsite");

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {

        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            CASsite.Dispose();
        }

    }

    [TestFixture, RequiresSTA]
    public class Tests : SetupClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void DoSomething()
        {

         }
    }
}
```

The error I keep receiving is : **Failure: TestFixtureSetUp failed in SetupClass**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have more than one `SetUpFixture` defined for your namespace `Testing`?

Per the docs,

> Only one SetUpFixture should be created in a given namespace.

Your `Tests` class derives from your `SetUpFixture` class.  You don't need to do that.  The `SetUpFixture` class' `SetUp` and `TearDown` will run automatically for all classes in that namespace.

Comment: I only have one SetUpFixture class and if I change the class declaration I still get the same issue.

Comment: So if you don't have `Tests` derive from `SetupClass` anymore, you still get the issue?

Comment: Actually, I missed this - but what is the IE class?  `public IE CASsite = new IE("awebsite");`  My guess is your problem is here.

Comment: Well I got it to run, just ideally I would like the Setup and Teardown to only run once each. So I want the setup to run, I want the tests to run through all on the same browser instance then I want them to close out with the teardown. Right now the setup runs before EACH individual test.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that your IE class is failing to initialize.